# python matplotlib clock signal type graph help:

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking to plot a graph that depicts a clock signal. The following is what I am looking forward to plot.

I have say four objects. Object one is either in state 1 or state 0 for a particular length of time. I also have to mention (some where on the top of the clock signal) how long is the zero period and how long is the 1 period.

I have to do the above procedure for rest of the three objects one over the other so that I can compare those clock signal type graphs. I have attached an image I want something on the lines of this image. Where out2 out1 etc are my objects and I mention the length of each 0 or 1 state above each graph. I do not want those clock and reset signals.

Can some one tell me what type of graph should I user from matplotlib library for this type of representation? how to plot each signal one over the other?

[image: clock signal graph. I want something like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To draw the lines themselves, use the `plot` method of an "axes" object. The `plot` method needs a range of `y` values for each signal. You'd have to generate those from your object, taking into account the required resolution. *[Edit: the `step` method seems to be even easier to use for clock-like singals. Thanks to Joe for pointing this out in a comment].*
- To draw them all together in the way you want, the best thing would be to use subplots (`add_subplot` method of a figure). You could alternatively just call `plot` several times on the same axes, but for that you'd have to compute the data points before-head to place the different signals separately vertically.

Comment: You might want to mention `plt.step` http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.step  in this particular case.

Comment: @user690682, don't forget to accept Eli's answer if this helped.  Click the grey check-box just under the votes to accept his answer.  If you don't accept answers, people may be more hesitant to assist in the future